# PHP, copying elements from multidimensional array to simple array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i need to copy inner elements from multidimmensional array of JSON to simple arrays.

For example: 
json looks lie that:

```
{
    "Point" : [
        {"x": 0, "y": 37, "z": 93},
        {"x": 1, "y": 81, "z": 44},
        {"x": 2, "y": 31, "z": 91},
        {"x": 3, "y": 45, "z": 6},
        ....
    ]
}
```

After json_parser, i need to copy each x, y and z to separate simple arrays like

x = array(1,2,3,4,...)
y = array(37,81,31,45,...), and so on.

Can you help me to solve that? i've tried everything i know or what i can understand - nothing works in the way i need.

Comment: I could supply the code but I decided to just give you a hint first: Loop the `Points` and add each `X`, `Y` and `Z` to corresponding arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$str = '{
"Point" : [
    {"x": 0, "y": 37, "z": 93},
    {"x": 1, "y": 81, "z": 44},
    {"x": 2, "y": 31, "z": 91},
    {"x": 3, "y": 45, "z": 6}
]
}';
$array = json_decode($str,true);
$x = array();
$y= array();
$z= array();
foreach($array['Point'] as $single)
{
  $x[] = $single['x'];
  $y[] = $single['y'];
  $z[] = $single['z'];
}
print_r($x);
print_r($y);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode('{
    "Point" : [
        {"x": 0, "y": 37, "z": 93},
        {"x": 1, "y": 81, "z": 44},
        {"x": 2, "y": 31, "z": 91},
        {"x": 3, "y": 45, "z": 6}
    ]
}', true);


foreach ($data['Point'] as $row) {
   foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
      $$key[] = $value;
   }
}

var_dump($x, $y, $z);
```

Note: `$key` will return `x`, `y` and `z`, so `$$key` will create $x, $y and $z.

```
$$key = ${$key} = ${'x'} = $x
```

A bit hacky but as this question is relatively easy, let's play a bit :-)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that.